# VRF Coordinator issue. Error value out-of-bounds (in relation to subscriptionId variable passed to constructor)

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I am trying to copy the Freecodecamp tutorial for blockchain + JS to write a game contract that utlizes chainlinks VRF. I am trying to deploy my contract locally and the mock deploy script runs fine, but the game contract deploy script breaks with the following error code:
"Error: value out-of-bounds (argument="subscriptionId", value="0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=abi/5.7.0)"

The Game contract code is as follows:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

/* Imports */
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/VRFCoordinatorV2Interface.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/VRFConsumerBaseV2.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AutomationCompatibleInterface.sol";

/* Errors */
error CoCWeb3__usernameAlreadyUsed();
error CoCWeb3__AddressFound(string username);
error CoCWeb3__UpkeepNotNeeded();

contract CodeofConflictWeb3 is VRFConsumerBaseV2, AutomationCompatibleInterface {
    /* Type declarations */
    /* State variables */

    // Chainlink VRF Variables
    VRFCoordinatorV2Interface private immutable i_vrfCoordinator;
    uint64 private immutable i_subscriptionId;
    bytes32 private immutable i_gasLane;
    uint32 private immutable i_callbackGasLimit;
    uint256 private immutable i_interval;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    //game
    address owner;

    /* Events */
    event NewPlayerCreated(address indexed playerAddress, string username);
    event AddressFound(address indexed existingAddress, string indexed playerUsername);
    event UsernameTaken(address indexed PlayerAddress);
    event RaidSuccessful(uint256 indexed percentage);
    event RaidUnsuccessful(uint256 indexed percentage);
    /* Functions */

    enum playerRank {
        LEVEL1,
        Level2,
        Level3
    }

    struct Players {
        string username;
        uint256 playerXP;
        playerRank rank;
        bool currentPlayer;
    }

    Players[] internal playersArray;

    mapping(address => Players) addressToPlayer; //

    Players player;

    modifier isOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "Not owner of contract");
        _;
    }

    constructor(
        address vrfCoordinatorV2,
        uint64 subscriptionId,
        bytes32 gasLane, // keyHash
        uint256 interval,
        uint32 callbackGasLimit
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2(vrfCoordinatorV2) {
        owner = msg.sender;
        i_vrfCoordinator = VRFCoordinatorV2Interface(vrfCoordinatorV2);
        i_gasLane = gasLane;
        i_interval = interval;
        i_subscriptionId = subscriptionId;
        i_callbackGasLimit = callbackGasLimit;
    }

    function createNewPlayer(string memory _name) public isOwner {
        if (addressToPlayer[msg.sender].currentPlayer == true) {
            revert CoCWeb3__AddressFound(addressToPlayer[msg.sender].username);
        }
        player = Players(_name, 0, playerRank(0), true);
        addressToPlayer[msg.sender] = player;
        playersArray.push(player);
        emit NewPlayerCreated(msg.sender, player.username);
    }

    function checkUpkeep(
        bytes memory /* checkData */
    ) public view override returns (bool upkeepNeeded, bytes memory /* performData */) {
        upkeepNeeded = true;
        return (upkeepNeeded, "0x0"); // can we comment this out?
    }

    /**
     * @dev Once `checkUpkeep` is returning `true`, this function is called
     * and it kicks off a Chainlink VRF call to get a random winner.
     */
    function performUpkeep(bytes calldata /* performData */) external override {
        (bool upkeepNeeded, ) = checkUpkeep("");
        // require(upkeepNeeded, "Upkeep not needed");
        if (!upkeepNeeded) {
            revert CoCWeb3__UpkeepNotNeeded();
        }
        uint256 requestId = i_vrfCoordinator.requestRandomWords(
            i_gasLane,
            i_subscriptionId,
            REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
            i_callbackGasLimit,
            NUM_WORDS
        );
        // Quiz... is this redundant?
        //emit RequestedRaffleWinner(requestId);
    }

    /**
     * @dev This is the function that Chainlink VRF node
     * calls to send the money to the random winner.
     */
    function fulfillRandomWords(
        uint256 /* requestId */,
        uint256[] memory randomWords
    ) internal override {
        // how to return a number between 1-100
        uint256 returnedNumber = randomWords[0] % 50;
        if (returnedNumber > 50) {
            emit RaidSuccessful(returnedNumber);
        } else {
            emit RaidUnsuccessful(returnedNumber);
        }
    }

    /** Getter Functions */

    function getOwner() public view returns (address) {
        return owner;
    }

    function getPlayer(address _player) public view returns (Players memory) {
        return addressToPlayer[_player];
    }
}
```

The deploy script in question is as follows:

```
const { ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const {
    networkConfig,
    developmentChains,
    VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS,
} = require("../helper-hardhat-config")
//const { verify } = require("../utils/verify")

const FUND_AMOUNT = ethers.utils.parseEther("1") // 1 Ether, or 1e18 (10^18) Wei

module.exports = async ({ getNamedAccounts, deployments }) => {
    const { deploy, log } = deployments
    const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
    const chainId = network.config.chainId
    let vrfCoordinatorV2Address, subscriptionId, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock

    if (chainId == 31337) {
        // create VRFV2 Subscription
        vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.address
        const transactionResponse = await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.createSubscription()
        const transactionReceipt = await transactionResponse.wait(1)
        subscriptionId = transactionReceipt.events[0].args.subId
        //ventranceFee = networkConfig[chainId]["raffleEntranceFee"]
        // Fund the subscription
        // Our mock makes it so we don't actually have to worry about sending fund
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.fundSubscription(subscriptionId, FUND_AMOUNT)
    } else {
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address = networkConfig[chainId]["vrfCoordinatorV2"]
        subscriptionId = networkConfig[chainId]["subscriptionId"]
    }
    const waitBlockConfirmations = developmentChains.includes(network.name)
        ? 1
        : VERIFICATION_BLOCK_CONFIRMATIONS

    const arguments = [
        vrfCoordinatorV2Address,
        networkConfig[chainId]["gasLane"],
        subscriptionId,
        networkConfig[chainId]["callbackGasLimit"],
        networkConfig[chainId]["keepersUpdateInterval"],
    ]

  log("---------------------------DEPLOY GAME CONTRACT-------------------------")

    const COCWeb3 = await deploy("CodeofConflictWeb3", {
        from: deployer,
        args: arguments,
        log: true,
        waitConfirmations: waitBlockConfirmations,
    })

    // Ensure the COCWeb3 contract is a valid consumer of the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract.
    if (developmentChains.includes(network.name)) {
        log(
            "--Ensure Game Raffle is Valid consumer of VRFCoordinator--"
        )
        const vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContract("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock")
        await vrfCoordinatorV2Mock.addConsumer(subscriptionId, COCWeb3.address)
    }

    // Verify the deployment
    if (!developmentChains.includes(network.name) && process.env.ETHERSCAN_API_KEY) {
        log("Verifying...")
        await verify(raffle.address, arguments)
    }

    log("Enter lottery with command:")
    const networkName = network.name == "hardhat" ? "localhost" : network.name
    log(`yarn hardhat run scripts/enterRaffle.js --network ${networkName}`)
    log("----------------------------------------------------")
}

module.exports.tags = ["all", "COCWeb3"]
```

Suggestions online are that the value of subscriptionId are incorrect.

When i use the javascript debug terminal, I can see in the variables section that the value of the subscriptionId is bigNumber with a hex of '0x01', which is the same as its value when i succesfullly deploy the freecodecamp tutorial.

However, the value that the error gives is "0x474e34a077df58807dbe9c96d3c009b23b3c6d0cce433e59bbf5b34f823bc56c". Is the value of subscriptionId that is being passed to my constructor? If so, I can't see what is overwriting the value of the subscriptionId in my deploy script?

This is my first question on here so please forgive misgivings in my formatting. If I need to clarify or rectify anything please let me know. Your assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was passing my arguments in the wrong order. Gaslane value was in place of SubscriptionId.